# Wired VS Wireless Mouse & Keyboard Security

Tags: physical, bluetooth

**Wired VS Wireless Mouse & Keyboard Security**

For someone who is trying to maintain the highest level of security, which option proposes the LEAST amount of security flaws?

> Wired Keyboard & Mouse?
>
> OR
>
> Wireless Keyboard & Mouse

I have also been seeing more and more articles like [this one](https://www.wired.com/2016/02/flaws-in-wireless-mice-and-keyboards-let-hackers-type-on-your-pc/) which states things like:

> The Bastille researchers claim that “more than a billion” devices are
>   affected in total.

So with wireless devices appearing compromised, what options does someone like me have? Should I use a wired keyboard and mouse, or should I use none of the above (If I'm using a Laptop with a built-in keyboard)? If anyone can shed some light on this subject, because I'm currently using a Logitech Wireless mouse & Keyboard which is great for convenience, I just hope I'm not conveniently giving up the cost of security.

Comment: Please note that the article you posted is about wireless devices using custom wireless chips. Bluetooth is encrypted.

Comment: Wow, what a crappy article and a bunch of FUD from the vendor ...

Comment: Sorry guys, when I initially made the post I made a comment about the USB Ruber Ducky. I realize now that by adding that it, complicated the real question of the post. I will try to keep my posts as clear as possible for now on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USB mice and keyboards are generally "safe" from known vendors and distributors, but then again you cannot really trust anything. nation state etc etc.

The Bastille research is based on wireless keyboards and mice that do not use encryption, or at least, does not force encryption (downgrade attack) or uses weak keys. This is the key point on the wireless keyboard.

So your options, use a built in keyboard or a wired keyboard or a keyboard that forces encryption only with strong non-reused keys. (good luck)

unless you build your own keyboard you will have to trust things, not sure on PS/2 security, but you could always go back to that!

Comment: PS/2 has tighter coupling with the motherboard and allows far fewer controls then USB. It's much safer.

Comment: @schroeder So you're saying that PS/2 keyboards are safer? If so would something like this be good: https://www.amazon.com/HP-Standard-104-key-Keyboard/dp/B004XBLDZS

Comment: @WatchDog yes, but it is highly unlkely you have a computer with PS\2...

Comment: @schroeder Oh good point. I didn't see that a ps/2 plug was required.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, wired beats wireless for security against remote access or disclosure. Wireless devices can be sniffed and code can be injected if one can decode the signals. You cannot restrict how far radio signals go, so a wired device provides a physically restricted channel.

But this is pretty obvious.

Both sets of devices are subject to malware being installed at the manufacturer, so there is no basis for comparison there.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't trust the manufacture then both wire and wireless mouse/keyboard could be malicious.

A malicious code in firmware of keyboard or mouse or even the BIOS itself will be executed regardless of the method used to transmit that malicious code to the CPU (through a wire or by radio frequency) it doesn't matter.

For more details checkout [this Black Hat talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nuruzFqMgIw)  About BadUSB